# Win 10 IoT on Raspberry Pi 3B: cannot find network connection

Tags: raspberry-pi, windows-10-iot-core

There is a project, last updated in Nov 2020, that needs a few changes. It is written in C#, using VisualStudio 2017. When I started the Raspberry recently, with the original SD card which I used for developing, the Raspberry could not find any network,  - LAN nor LAN. I re-installed the IoT dashboard, flashed the OS to a new SD card (Sandisk ultra, 16 GB), replaced network cable, but still no network. What's different: I use VisualStudio 2022 now. But that can not have an impact on the Raspberry which had been untouched for 2 years - after re-installing the newest version of IoT dashboard it could.

I tried the Raspberry with Raspbian OS and it showed all available networks, so it is not a hardware issue.

Are there any known issues? It is not a Raspberry Pi 3B+, which is said to be not supported.
I would be grateful for any hint!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The firewall blocked IoT-dashboard. Obviously one has to format and re-flash the SD card after the firewall allows IoT-dashobard.